# Set of lattice points in an n-dimensional hyperbox for which the sum of its coordinates is $\leq g$ and $> h$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Consider an $n$-dimensional box where $n \geq 2$. The dimensions of the box are always integers.

I want to find the set of lattice points inside the box for which the sum if its separate coordinates is $\leq g$ and $> h$ where $h < g$ and both $h$ and $g$ are integers.

In 2-d it would look like this:

[image: example]

For convenience (if it matters) we can assume that the coordinates of the box are all $\geq 0$, and one of the vertices is at the origin.

I want to be able to tell the cardinality of resulting the set.
The resulting figure is a polytope, but calculating the number of lattice points with a package like [Polytope](https://pypi.org/project/polytope/) becomes impossible when numbers get large enough. I do think however that this is a special case for which a simpeler solution should exist.

Comment: Let's say that $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is an arbitrary integer point in the green region. This means that
$$h<x_1+\dots+x_n\le g$$You want to count the number of solutions to that inequality, for which $a_i\le x_i\le b_i$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, where $a_i,b_i$ are the bounds of the box in the $i^\text{th}$ dimension (so the volume is $(b_1-a_1)\times \dots \times (b_n-a_n)$). Have I interpreted your problem correctly?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Your "volume" is defined by inequations, therefore it is a polytope (though the term is usually reserved to continuous variables).

Comment: @JeanMarie but the main question remains: what is the cardinality of that set?

Comment: See "Ehrhart polynomials" as described [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/RECENT_WORK/semesterberichte.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This is a $\# P$-hard problem in general, which means that it is really hard to solve exactly.

To see why this is true, WLOG assume that the box is $[0, a_1 - 1] \times \cdots [0, a_n - 1]$, with $a_i$ integers and take $g = h + 1$. Then we want to count the number of solutions of
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_n = g, 0 \leq x_i \leq a_i - 1.$$
The number of solutions can be computed as the coefficient of $x^g$ in the following polynomial
$$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + \cdots x^{a_i - 1}) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{1 - x^{a_i}}{1 - x}.$$
This can be expanded as
$$\sum_{S \subset[n]} (-1)^{|S|} \frac{x^{a_S}}{(1 - x)^n} = \sum_{S \subset[n]} \sum_{a \geq a_S}(-1)^{|S|} \binom{a - a_S + n - 1}{n - 1} x^a$$
where $a_S = \sum_{i \in S} a_i$.  So the number of solutions is
$$f(g) = \sum_{S \subset[n]} \mathbf{1}_{g \geq a_S} (-1)^{|S|} \binom{g - a_S + n - 1}{n - 1}.$$
We now note that $f(g - m)$ is the coefficient of $x^g$ in the polynomial
$$x^{m}\prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{1 - x^{a_i}}{1 - x}$$
So $\sum_{0 \leq m \leq n} (-1)^m \binom{n}{m} f(g - m)$ is the coefficient of $x^g$ in the polynomial
$$\sum_{0 \leq m \leq n} (-1)^m \binom{n}{m} x^{m}\prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{1 - x^{a_i}}{1 - x} = \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 - x^{a_i}).$$
Therefore, given an oracle computing $f(g)$, we can efficiently compute
$$\sum_{S \subset [n]} (-1)^S \mathbf{1}_{a_S = g} = \sum_{m \leq n} (-1)^m \binom{n}{m} f(g - m).$$
This is a counting variation of subset sum. It is not hard to show that this version is $\# P$-complete. Here is an outline on how to do this.

1. By adding large constants to $a_S$, we can efficiently compute
   $$\sum_{|S| = k, S \subset [n]} \mathbf{1}_{a_S = g}.$$
   So it suffices to show that counting solutions $S$ to $a_S = g, |S| = k, S \subset [n]$ is $\# P$-complete
2. We can encode an instance of perfect matching into this problem. Let $G = ([n], [n], E)$ be a bipartite graph. For each $e = (u, v) \in E$, let $a_e = n^u + n^{n + v}$. Then each perfect matching corresponds to a solution to
   $$a_S = \sum_{i \in [n]} n^i + n^{n + i}, |S| = n.$$
   Finally, counting the number of perfect matching is $\# P$-complete.

Comment: I am very grateful for the effort you put into this answer. Sadly, it is too complicated for me to follow. (Which is completely my shortcoming). But I understand that by proving that it is #P-complete, we determine the problem to be near impossible to solve exactly. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: yes, it is hard to solve the problem efficiently in the most general case.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the paper written by [Hendrik Lenstra](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237551951_Lattices) about lattices, section 12, paragraph ‘Enumerating all short vectors’. Notice that it uses the LLL-algorithm, so that might be a good start to count the lattice points in a given cube for the standard (integers) lattice.